# how to make successfull ajax success

Tags: ajax, laravel, e-commerce

**Button code**
this is my button code with id 123

```
<button type="submit" class="addto" id="123">Add to cart</button>
```

**ajax code**
This is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.addto').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $id=this.id;
                //alert($id);
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/test', //route url
                    dataType:"json",
                    type:"POST",
                    data:{id:this.id},
                    success: function(result){ //success function
                        alert("success");  //test alert
                }});
            });
        });
```

**Route code**
this is my route code

```
Route::match(['get','post'],'/test','ajaxcontrol@test'); //route url
```

**Controller code:**
How to solve this, i have included all the imports

```
class ajaxcontrol extends Controller
{
    public function test(Request $request){
        $valu=$request->id;
        echo json_encode($valu);            
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Sometimes it shows 409 and 419

Comment: We are going to need more specifics than that to help you out, friend :) You are going to need to get more information on what is causing the 500.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your ajax like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.addto').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            id=this.id;
            //console.log(id);
           
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url('/test') }}", //route url
                dataType:"json",
                type:"POST",
                data:{
                id:id,
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                },
                success: function(result){ //success function
                    alert("success");  //test alert
            }});
        });
    });
```

Comment: if there is error 500; then you have error in the web.php or your controller, try to change class ajaxcontrol extends Controller
{
    public function test(Request $request){
        dd($request->id);      
    }
}

Comment: Route::match(['get','post'],'/test','ajaxcontrol@test');